# MATLAB using unicode characters in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, unicode

I want to use Tamil word (Tamil is an Indian language) in list box of MATLAB guide instead of default English word. How to do that?

Comment: It requires more details that you have tried so far to give you the desired answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MATLAB listboxes can't display Unicode. However, you can display Unicode by using a Java listbox in your GUI instead:

```
f = figure;
txt = char(hex2dec('0B85'),hex2dec('0B86'),hex2dec('0B87'));
b = javax.swing.JList({'hello','hello2',txt});
c = javacomponent(b,[20,20,500,100],f);
fn = java.awt.Font('Arial Unicode MS',0,10);
set(b,'font',fn)
```

The variable `txt` contains some Tamil characters found from the Wikipedia page on Unicode - my apologies if it says anything rude :)

The command `javacomponent` is undocumented and may change from release to release, so don't rely on it if your application is important. You'll need a Unicode font as well - I've used Arial Unicode MS, but if you're not on Windows you'll need a different one.

Lastly, if you're using `javacomponent`, I'd recommend that you move away from GUIDE for developing your GUI - it will become difficult to manage.